# When did Visual Basic become object-oriented?

Tags: vb.net, oop, vb6

Given the 50th anniversary of BASIC, I was reading the Wikipedia article and [the section on VB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC#Visual_Basic) indicated that "more recently" it became object-oriented.

Apparently I need to clarify that it is [commonly understood that object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_oriented_programming#Fundamental_features_and_concepts) includes implementation inheritance and polymorphic behaviour. It has been asserted VB.NET 2002 is object-oriented.  I understand that VB.NET 2002 followed VB6.

Did VB6 have implementation inheritance and polymorphic behaviour?  Did VB.NET 2002 have implementation inheritance and polymorphic behaviour?  Did VB.NET 2002 have the other aspects of object-orientation?

The [Wikipedia article on VB.NET 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) gives both 2001 and 2002 as the date of release. When was VB.NET 2002 "released"?

Comment: Since vb.net was introduced.

Comment: Nonsense.  VB was object oriented as early as VB-DOS 1.0, while VB.Net is arguably not even VB at all.

Comment: Rut roh.  It depends on how you define "object oriented".  If it means that it has to support implementation inheritance, then yes, VB.Net.  If it means that some form of inheritance needs to be supported, then VB5.  If it means that you can define objects with properties and methods, then like Bob77 says.

Answer (score 5):

VB6 was not object-oriented, although it had some features that were influenced by OOP.  VB.NET is object-oriented.  The first version of VB.NET was VB.NET 2002.  Anything since then is managed and OO and anything before that is not OO.

Comment: The term I remember being used for VB 6 was **object-based**, as opposed to object-oriented. And although this is the correct answer, the asker indicated he wanted a "reliable source" (presumably he's crowd-sourcing a wikipedia edit). The only source I know of is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55yzhfb2(v=vs.80).aspx), which is actually a pretty good comparison of the OO capabilities of VB 6 with VB.NET (it talks about VB.NET 2005, but the original version of VB.NET was not significantly different in its OO support).

Comment: OO does not mean "managed."  Hair splitters like to claim VB6 is not "object oriented" but there isn't any fence you cross to get there.  It really means they have an axe to grind, and parrot common wisdom (which ain't that wise) to support a weak argument.

Comment: @Bob77, noone said that OO meant managed.  I said that VB.NET is managed **AND** OO, implying that it was both, implying that they are two different things.  I specified that VB.NET is managed to distinguish it from prior versions that are not managed.  As for VB6 being OO, it is not.  There's no hair-splitting or axe-grinding.  It just isn't.  Inheritance is one of the central pillars of OO.  Does VB6 support inheritance?  I rest my case.  It rather sounds like you have an axe to grind, assuming that saying that it's not OO is an attack on VB6 developers when it's just a statement of fact.

Comment: Here we go with more opinion.  Move to close.

Comment: @CodyGray : thanks for the link. sums it up pretty nicely!

Comment: It's just unnecessary to mention managed memory, since it's totally orthogonal to object-orientation.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, ugh!  I specified that VB.NET 2003 and later are managed to differentiate them from VB6 and earlier that are not managed, i.e. any managed version of VB is OO and any that isn't is not.  I didn't say or even imply that there was any sort of causal relationship between the two.  I said that because many people seem not to realise that VB 2005 and later are .NET-based because they don't have the ".NET" suffix.  I wasn't aware that its being "strictly necessary" was a condition for including a statement in an answer.

Comment: Cody is correct: VB6 was often called object-based, because it has support for some of the classic pillars of OO: abstraction, encapsulation, polymorphism, [interface inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ab292ze(v=vs.90).aspx); but not implementation inheritance or method overloading. Those were added in Vb.Net.